# Newspaper Bill Calculator CLI with Python (3 of 3, Database)

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

Code is posted after explanation.

Due to the size of the project, this is being posted in three separate posts. This also ensures each post is more focused.

- Post 1 of 3, Core: [Newspaper Bill Calculator CLI with Python (1 of 3, Core)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/276225/257004)
- Post 2 of 3, CLI: [Newspaper Bill Calculator CLI with Python (2 of 3, CLI)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/276227/257004)

---

##### What is this?

This application helps you calculate monthly newspaper bills. The goal is to generate a message that I can paste into WhatsApp and send to my newspaper vendor. The end result here is a CLI tool that will be later used as a back-end to build GUIs (hence learn about: C#, HTML/CSS/JS, Flutter). In its current form, everything will be "compiled" by PyInstaller into one-file stand-alone executables for the end-user using GitHub Actions.

The other important goal was to be a testbed for learning a bunch of new tools: more Python libraries, SQL connectors, GitHub Actions (CI/CD, if I understand correctly), unit tests, CLI libraries, type-hinting, regex. I had [earlier built](https://github.com/eccentricOrange/Newspaper-Bill-Calculator-v2) this on a different platform, so I now have a solid idea of how this application is used.

##### Key concepts

1. Each newspaper has a certain cost per day of the week
2. Each newspaper may or may not be delivered on a given day
3. Each newspaper has a name, and a number called a key
4. You may register any dates when you didn't receive a paper in advance using the `addudl` command
5. Once you calculate, the results are displayed and copied to your clipboard

##### What files exist?

(ignoring conventional ones like `README` and `requirements.txt`)

| File | Purpose/Description | Review |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `npbc_core.py` | Provide the core functionality: the calculation, parsing and validation of user input, interaction with the DB etc. Later on, some functionality from this will be extracted to create server-side code that can service more users, but I have to learn a lot more before getting there. | Please review this. |
| `npbc_cli.py` | Import functionality from `npbc_core.py` and wrap a CLI layer on it using `argparse`. Also provide some additional validation. | Please review this. |
| `npbc_updater.py` | Provide a utility to update the application on the user's end. | Don't bother reviewing this (code not included). |
| `test_core.py` | Test the functionality of the core file (pytest). This isn't as exhaustive as I'd like, but it did a good job of capturing many of my mistakes. | Please review this. |
| `data/schema.sql` | Database schema. In my local environment, the `data` folder also has a test database file (but I don't want to upload this online). | Please review this if you can (not high priority). |

##### Known problems

- Tests are not exhaustive (please suggest anything you think of).
- Tests are not well commented (working on this right now in a local branch).
- SQL injection is possible in some cases by `-k`/`--key` CLI parameters, if you can figure out a way to insert a semicolon in an integer. I will remove this in a future version, once I find a way to improve or remove the `generate_sql_query()` function.
- A lot of documentation is tied up in the CLI UI and comments, and is not an explicit document.

---

## `data/schema.sql` (SQLite 3)

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS papers (
    paper_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT unique_paper_name UNIQUE (name)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS papers_days_delivered (
    paper_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    day_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    delivered INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(paper_id) REFERENCES papers(paper_id),
    CONSTRAINT unique_paper_day UNIQUE (paper_id, day_id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS papers_days_cost(
    paper_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    day_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cost INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(paper_id) REFERENCES papers(paper_id),
    CONSTRAINT unique_paper_day UNIQUE (paper_id, day_id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS undelivered_strings (
    entry_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    year INTEGER NOT NULL,
    month INTEGER NOT NULL,
    paper_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    string TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (paper_id) REFERENCES papers(paper_id)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS undelivered_dates (
    entry_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    timestamp TEXT NOT NULL,
    year INTEGER NOT NULL,
    month INTEGER NOT NULL,
    paper_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    dates TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (paper_id) REFERENCES papers(paper_id)
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS search_strings ON undelivered_strings(year, month);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS paper_names ON papers(name);
```

---

## All code where a query/call to DB is made

This is provided for context, and is duplicated from the other posts.

### `npbc_core.py`

#### Setup

```py
from sqlite3 import connect
from pathlib import Path

## paths for the folder containing schema and database files
 # during normal use, the DB will be in ~/.npbc (where ~ is the user's home directory) and the schema will be bundled with the executable
 # during development, the DB and schema will both be in "data"

DATABASE_DIR = Path().home() / '.npbc'  # normal use path
# DATABASE_DIR = Path('data')  # development path

DATABASE_PATH = DATABASE_DIR / 'npbc.db'

SCHEMA_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / 'schema.sql'  # normal use path
# SCHEMA_PATH = DATABASE_DIR / 'schema.sql'  # development path

## ensure DB exists and it's set up with the schema
def setup_and_connect_DB() -> None:
    DATABASE_DIR.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    DATABASE_PATH.touch(exist_ok=True)

    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        connection.executescript(SCHEMA_PATH.read_text())
        connection.commit()
```

#### Query generator

```py
## generate a "SELECT" SQL query
 # use params to specify columns to select, and "WHERE" conditions
def generate_sql_query(table_name: str, conditions: dict[str, int | str] | None = None, columns: list[str] | None = None) -> str:
    sql_query = f"SELECT"
    
    if columns:
        sql_query += f" {', '.join(columns)}"
    
    else:
        sql_query += f" *"
    
    sql_query += f" FROM {table_name}"

    if conditions:
        conditions_segment = ' AND '.join([
            f"{parameter_name} = {parameter_value}"
            for parameter_name, parameter_value in conditions.items()
        ])
        
        sql_query += f" WHERE {conditions_segment}"

    return f"{sql_query};"
```

#### Query (call to DB)

```py
## execute a "SELECT" SQL query and return the results
def query_database(query: str) -> list[tuple]:
    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        return connection.execute(query).fetchall()
    
    return []
```

#### Fetching data about a given paper, used in calculation

```py
## get the cost and delivery data for a given paper from the DB
 # each of them are converted to a dictionary, whose index is the day_id
 # the two dictionaries are then returned as a tuple
def get_cost_and_delivery_data(paper_id: int) -> tuple[dict[int, float], dict[int, bool]]:
    cost_query = generate_sql_query(
        'papers_days_cost',
        columns=['day_id', 'cost'],
        conditions={'paper_id': paper_id}
    )

    delivery_query = generate_sql_query(
        'papers_days_delivered',
        columns=['day_id', 'delivered'],
        conditions={'paper_id': paper_id}
    )

    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        cost_tuple = connection.execute(cost_query).fetchall()
        delivery_tuple = connection.execute(delivery_query).fetchall()

    cost_dict = {
        day_id: cost
        for day_id, cost in cost_tuple # type: ignore
    }

    delivery_dict = {
        day_id: delivery
        for day_id, delivery in delivery_tuple # type: ignore
    }

    return cost_dict, delivery_dict
```

#### Main calculation function

```py
## calculate the cost of all papers for the full month
 # return data about the cost of each paper, the total cost, and dates when each paper was not delivered
def calculate_cost_of_all_papers(undelivered_strings: dict[int, str], month: int, year: int) -> tuple[dict[int, float], float, dict[int, set[date_type]]]:
    NUMBER_OF_DAYS_PER_WEEK = get_number_of_days_per_week(month, year)

    # get the IDs of papers that exist
    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        papers = connection.execute(
            generate_sql_query(
                'papers',
                columns=['paper_id']
            )
        ).fetchall()

    # get the data about cost and delivery for each paper
    cost_and_delivery_data = [
        get_cost_and_delivery_data(paper_id)
        for paper_id, in papers # type: ignore
    ]

    # initialize a "blank" dictionary that will eventually contain any dates when a paper was not delivered
    undelivered_dates: dict[int, set[date_type]] = {
        paper_id: {}
        for paper_id, in papers # type: ignore
    }

    # calculate the undelivered dates for each paper
    for paper_id, undelivered_string in undelivered_strings.items(): # type: ignore
        undelivered_dates[paper_id] = parse_undelivered_string(undelivered_string, month, year)

    # calculate the cost of each paper
    costs = {
        paper_id: calculate_cost_of_one_paper(
            NUMBER_OF_DAYS_PER_WEEK,
            undelivered_dates[paper_id],
            cost_and_delivery_data[index]
        )
        for index, (paper_id,) in enumerate(papers) # type: ignore
    }

    # calculate the total cost of all papers
    total = sum(costs.values())

    return costs, total, undelivered_dates
```

#### Save results

```py
## save the results of undelivered dates to the DB
 # save the dates any paper was not delivered
def save_results(undelivered_dates: dict[int, set[date_type]], month: int, year: int) -> None:
    TIMESTAMP = datetime.now().strftime(r'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        for paper_id, undelivered_date_instances in undelivered_dates.items():
            connection.execute(
                "INSERT INTO undelivered_dates (timestamp, month, year, paper_id, dates) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);",
                (
                    TIMESTAMP,
                    month,
                    year,
                    paper_id,
                    ','.join([
                        undelivered_date_instance.strftime(r'%d')
                        for undelivered_date_instance in undelivered_date_instances
                    ])
                )
            )
```

#### Add, edit, or delete papers

```py
## add a new paper
 # do not allow if the paper already exists
def add_new_paper(name: str, days_delivered: list[bool], days_cost: list[float]) -> tuple[bool, str]:
    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:

        # get the names of all papers that already exist
        paper = connection.execute(
            generate_sql_query('papers', columns=['name'], conditions={'name': f"\"{name}\""})
        ).fetchall()

        # if the proposed paper already exists, return an error message
        if paper:
            return False, "Paper already exists. Please try editing the paper instead."
        
        # otherwise, add the paper name to the database
        connection.execute(
            "INSERT INTO papers (name) VALUES (?);",
            (name, )
        )

        # get the ID of the paper that was just added
        paper_id = connection.execute(
            "SELECT paper_id FROM papers WHERE name = ?;",
            (name, )
        ).fetchone()[0]

        # add the cost and delivery data for the paper
        for day_id, (cost, delivered) in enumerate(zip(days_cost, days_delivered)):
            connection.execute(
                "INSERT INTO papers_days_cost (paper_id, day_id, cost) VALUES (?, ?, ?);",
                (paper_id, day_id, cost)
            )
            connection.execute(
                "INSERT INTO papers_days_delivered (paper_id, day_id, delivered) VALUES (?, ?, ?);",
                (paper_id, day_id, delivered)
            )
        
        connection.commit()

        return True, f"Paper {name} added."

    return False, "Something went wrong."


## edit an existing paper
 # do not allow if the paper does not exist
def edit_existing_paper(paper_id: int, name: str | None = None, days_delivered: list[bool] | None = None, days_cost: list[float] | None = None) -> tuple[bool, str]:
    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:

        # get the IDs of all papers that already exist
        paper = connection.execute(
            generate_sql_query('papers', columns=['paper_id'], conditions={'paper_id': paper_id})
        ).fetchone()

        # if the proposed paper does not exist, return an error message
        if not paper:
            return False, f"Paper {paper_id} does not exist. Please try adding it instead."

        # if a name is proposed, update the name of the paper
        if name is not None:
            connection.execute(
                "UPDATE papers SET name = ? WHERE paper_id = ?;",
                (name, paper_id)
            )
        
        # if delivery data is proposed, update the delivery data of the paper
        if days_delivered is not None:
            for day_id, delivered in enumerate(days_delivered):
                connection.execute(
                    "UPDATE papers_days_delivered SET delivered = ? WHERE paper_id = ? AND day_id = ?;",
                    (delivered, paper_id, day_id)
                )

        # if cost data is proposed, update the cost data of the paper
        if days_cost is not None:
            for day_id, cost in enumerate(days_cost):
                connection.execute(
                    "UPDATE papers_days_cost SET cost = ? WHERE paper_id = ? AND day_id = ?;",
                    (cost, paper_id, day_id)
                )

        connection.commit()

        return True, f"Paper {paper_id} edited."

    return False, "Something went wrong."


## delete an existing paper
 # do not allow if the paper does not exist
def delete_existing_paper(paper_id: int) -> tuple[bool, str]:
    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:

        # get the IDs of all papers that already exist
        paper = connection.execute(
            generate_sql_query('papers', columns=['paper_id'], conditions={'paper_id': paper_id})
        ).fetchone()

        # if the proposed paper does not exist, return an error message
        if not paper:
            return False, f"Paper {paper_id} does not exist. Please try adding it instead."

        # delete the paper from the names table
        connection.execute(
            "DELETE FROM papers WHERE paper_id = ?;",
            (paper_id, )
        )

        # delete the paper from the delivery data table
        connection.execute(
            "DELETE FROM papers_days_delivered WHERE paper_id = ?;",
            (paper_id, )
        )

        # delete the paper from the cost data table
        connection.execute(
            "DELETE FROM papers_days_cost WHERE paper_id = ?;",
            (paper_id, )
        )

        connection.commit()

        return True, f"Paper {paper_id} deleted."

    return False, "Something went wrong."
```

#### Add or delete undelivered strings

```py
## record strings for date(s) paper(s) were not delivered
def add_undelivered_string(paper_id: int, undelivered_string: str, month: int, year: int) -> tuple[bool, str]:
    
    # if the string is not valid, return an error message
    if not validate_undelivered_string(undelivered_string):
        return False, f"Invalid undelivered string."
    
    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        # check if given paper exists
        paper = connection.execute(
            generate_sql_query(
                'papers',
                columns=['paper_id'],
                conditions={'paper_id': paper_id}
            )
        ).fetchone()

        # if the paper does not exist, return an error message
        if not paper:
            return False, f"Paper {paper_id} does not exist. Please try adding it instead."

        # check if a string with the same month and year, for the same paper, already exists
        existing_string = connection.execute(
            generate_sql_query(
                'undelivered_strings',
                columns=['string'],
                conditions={
                    'paper_id': paper_id,
                    'month': month,
                    'year': year
                }
            )
        ).fetchone()

        # if a string with the same month and year, for the same paper, already exists, concatenate the new string to it
        if existing_string:
            new_string = f"{existing_string[0]},{undelivered_string}"

            connection.execute(
                "UPDATE undelivered_strings SET string = ? WHERE paper_id = ? AND month = ? AND year = ?;",
                (new_string, paper_id, month, year)
            )

        # otherwise, add the new string to the database
        else:
            connection.execute(
                "INSERT INTO undelivered_strings (string, paper_id, month, year) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);",
                (undelivered_string, paper_id, month, year)
            )

        connection.commit()

    return True, f"Undelivered string added."


## delete an existing undelivered string
 # do not allow if the string does not exist
def delete_undelivered_string(paper_id: int, month: int, year: int) -> tuple[bool, str]:
    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
    
        # check if a string with the same month and year, for the same paper, exists
        existing_string = connection.execute(
            generate_sql_query(
                'undelivered_strings',
                columns=['string'],
                conditions={
                    'paper_id': paper_id,
                    'month': month,
                    'year': year
                }
            )
        ).fetchone()

        # if it does, delete it
        if existing_string:
            connection.execute(
                "DELETE FROM undelivered_strings WHERE paper_id = ? AND month = ? AND year = ?;",
                (paper_id, month, year)
            )

            connection.commit()

            return True, f"Undelivered string deleted."

        # if the string does not exist, return an error message
        return False, f"Undelivered string does not exist."

    return False, "Something went wrong."
```

#### Extract data from user input

```py
## extract delivery days and costs from user input
def extract_days_and_costs(days_delivered: str | None, prices: str | None, paper_id: int | None = None) -> tuple[list[bool], list[float]]:
    days = []
    costs = []

    # if the user has provided delivery days, extract them
    if days_delivered is not None:
        days = [
            bool(int(day == 'Y')) for day in str(days_delivered).upper()
        ]

    # if the user has not provided delivery days, fetch them from the database
    else:
        if isinstance(paper_id, int):
            days = [
                (int(day_id), bool(delivered))
                for day_id, delivered in query_database(
                    generate_sql_query(
                        'papers_days_delivered',
                        columns=['day_id', 'delivered'],
                        conditions={
                            'paper_id': paper_id
                        }
                    )
                )
            ]

            days.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

            days = [delivered for _, delivered in days]

    # if the user has provided prices, extract them
    if prices is not None:

        costs = []
        encoded_prices = [float(price) for price in SPLIT_REGEX['semicolon'].split(prices.rstrip(';')) if float(price) > 0]

        day_count = -1
        for day in days:
            if day:
                day_count += 1
                cost = encoded_prices[day_count]

            else:
                cost = 0

            costs.append(cost)

    return days, costs
```

### `npbc_cli.py`

#### Calculate the costs

```py
## calculate the cost for a given month and year
 # default to the previous month if no month and no year is given
 # default to the current month if no month is given and year is given
 # default to the current year if no year is given and month is given
def calculate(args: arg_namespace) -> None:

    # deal with month and year
    if args.month or args.year:

        feedback = validate_month_and_year(args.month, args.year)

        if not feedback[0]:
            status_print(*feedback)
            return

        if args.month:
            month = args.month
        
        else:
            month = datetime.now().month

        if args.year:
            year = args.year

        else:
            year = datetime.now().year

    else:
        previous_month = get_previous_month()
        month = previous_month.month
        year = previous_month.year

    # look for undelivered strings in the database
    existing_strings = query_database(
        generate_sql_query(
            'undelivered_strings',
            columns=['paper_id', 'string'],
            conditions={
                'month': month,
                'year': year
            }
        )
    )

    # associate undelivered strings with their paper_id
    undelivered_strings: dict[int, str] = {
        paper_id: undelivered_string
        for paper_id, undelivered_string in existing_strings
    }

    # calculate the cost for each paper, as well as the total cost
    costs, total, undelivered_dates = calculate_cost_of_all_papers(
        undelivered_strings,
        month,
        year
    )

    # format the results
    formatted = format_output(costs, total, month, year)

    # unless the user specifies so, copy the results to the clipboard
    if not args.nocopy:
        copy_to_clipboard(formatted)

        formatted += '\nSummary copied to clipboard.'

    # unless the user specifies so, log the results to the database
    if not args.nolog:
        save_results(undelivered_dates, month, year)

        formatted += '\nLog saved to file.'

    # print the results
    status_print(True, "Success!")
    print(f"SUMMARY:\n{formatted}")
```

#### Get undelivered strings, paper data, or logs

```py
## get undelivered strings from the database
 # filter by whichever parameter the user provides. they as many as they want.
 # available parameters: month, year, key, string
def getudl(args: arg_namespace) -> None:

    # validate the month and year
    feedback = validate_month_and_year(args.month, args.year)

    if not feedback[0]:
        status_print(*feedback)
        return
    
    conditions = {}

    if args.key:
        conditions['paper_id'] = args.key

    if args.month:
        conditions['month'] = args.month

    if args.year:
        conditions['year'] = args.year

    if args.undelivered:
        conditions['strings'] = str(args.undelivered).lower().strip()

        if not validate_undelivered_string(conditions['strings']):
            status_print(False, "Invalid undelivered string.")
            return

    # if the undelivered strings exist, fetch them
    undelivered_strings = query_database(
        generate_sql_query(
            'undelivered_strings',
            conditions=conditions
        )
    )

    # if there were undelivered strings, print them
    if undelivered_strings:
        status_print(True, 'Found undelivered strings.')

        print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}entry_id{Style.RESET_ALL} | {Fore.YELLOW}year{Style.RESET_ALL} | {Fore.YELLOW}month{Style.RESET_ALL} | {Fore.YELLOW}paper_id{Style.RESET_ALL} | {Fore.YELLOW}string{Style.RESET_ALL}")
        
        for string in undelivered_strings:
            print('|'.join([str(item) for item in string]))

    # otherwise, print that there were no undelivered strings
    else:
        status_print(False, 'No undelivered strings found.')

## get a list of all papers in the database
 # filter by whichever parameter the user provides. they may use as many as they want (but keys are always printed)
 # available parameters: name, days, costs
 # the output is provided as a formatted table, printed to the standard output
def getpapers(args: arg_namespace) -> None:
    headers = ['paper_id']

    # fetch a list of all papers' IDs
    papers_id_list = [
        paper_id
        for paper_id, in query_database(
            generate_sql_query(
                'papers',
                columns=['paper_id']
            )
        )
    ]

    # initialize lists for the data
    paper_name_list, paper_days_list, paper_costs_list = [], [], []

    # sort the papers' IDs (for the sake of consistency)
    papers_id_list.sort()

    # if the user wants names, fetch that data and add it to the list
    if args.names:

        # first get a dictionary of {paper_id: paper_name}
        papers_names = {
            paper_id: paper_name
            for paper_id, paper_name in query_database(
                generate_sql_query(
                    'papers',
                    columns=['paper_id', 'name']
                )
            )
        }

        # then use the sorted IDs list to create a sorted names list
        paper_name_list = [
            papers_names[paper_id]
            for paper_id in papers_id_list
        ]

        headers.append('name')

    # if the user wants delivery days, fetch that data and add it to the list
    if args.days:

        # initialize a dictionary of {paper_id: {day_id: delivery}}
        papers_days = {
            paper_id: {}
            for paper_id in papers_id_list
        }

        # then get the data for each paper
        for paper_id, day_id, delivered in query_database(
            generate_sql_query(
                'papers_days_delivered',
                columns=['paper_id', 'day_id', 'delivered']
            )
        ):
            papers_days[paper_id][day_id] = delivered

        # format the data so that it matches the regex pattern /^[YN]{7}$/, the same way the user must input this data
        paper_days_list = [
            ''.join([
                'Y' if int(papers_days[paper_id][day_id]) == 1 else 'N'
                for day_id, _ in enumerate(WEEKDAY_NAMES)
            ])
            for paper_id in papers_id_list
        ]

        headers.append('days')

    # if the user wants costs, fetch that data and add it to the list
    if args.prices:

        # initialize a dictionary of {paper_id: {day_id: price}}
        papers_costs = {
            paper_id: {}
            for paper_id in papers_id_list
        }

        # then get the data for each paper
        for paper_id, day_id, cost in query_database(
            generate_sql_query(
                'papers_days_cost',
                columns=['paper_id', 'day_id', 'cost']
            )
        ):
            papers_costs[paper_id][day_id] = cost

        # format the data so that it matches the regex pattern /^[x](;[x]){6}$/, where /x/ is a number that may be either a floating point or an integer, the same way the user must input this data.
        paper_costs_list = [
            ';'.join([
                str(papers_costs[paper_id][day_id])
                for day_id, _ in enumerate(WEEKDAY_NAMES)
            ])
            for paper_id in papers_id_list
        ]

        headers.append('costs')

    # print the headers
    print(' | '.join([
        f"{Fore.YELLOW}{header}{Style.RESET_ALL}"
        for header in headers
    ]))

    # print the data
    for index, paper_id in enumerate(papers_id_list):
        print(f"{paper_id}: ", end='')
        
        values = []

        if args.names:
            values.append(paper_name_list[index])

        if args.days:
            values.append(paper_days_list[index])

        if args.prices:
            values.append(paper_costs_list[index])

        print(', '.join(values))


## get a log of all deliveries for a paper
 # the user may specify parameters to filter the output by. they may use as many as they want, or none
 # available parameters: paper_id, month, year
def getlogs(args: arg_namespace) -> None:
    
    # validate the month and year
    feedback = validate_month_and_year(args.month, args.year)

    if not feedback[0]:
        status_print(*feedback)
        return
        
    conditions = {}

    # if the user specified a particular paper, add it to the conditions
    if args.key:
        conditions['paper_id'] = args.key

    if args.month:
        conditions['month'] = args.month

    if args.year:
        conditions['year'] = args.year

    # fetch the data
    undelivered_dates = query_database(
        generate_sql_query(
            'undelivered_dates',
            conditions=conditions
        )
    )

    # if data was found, print it
    if undelivered_dates:
        status_print(True, 'Success!')

        print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}entry_id{Style.RESET_ALL} | {Fore.YELLOW}year{Style.RESET_ALL} | {Fore.YELLOW}month{Style.RESET_ALL} | {Fore.YELLOW}paper_id{Style.RESET_ALL} | {Fore.YELLOW}dates{Style.RESET_ALL}")

        for date in undelivered_dates:
            print(', '.join(date))

    # if no data was found, print an error message
    else:
        status_print(False, 'No results found.')
```

---

If you need it, here is a link to the GitHub repo for this project. It's at the same commit as the code above, and I won't edit this so that any discussion is consistent.

https://github.com/eccentricOrange/npbc/tree/6020a4f5db0bf40f54e35b725b305cfeafdd8f2b

Comment: @Reinderien Edited with the requested code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite supports [check constraints](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#ckconst). You should use them to ensure that

- `delivered` is only 0 or 1 (since booleans are not supported directly)
- `cost` is greater than 0
- `year` is between perhaps 2000 and 2100
- `month` is between 0 and 11

[Inline foreign key clauses](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/foreign-key-clause.html) are supported which are nicer to read than table-level clauses, so consider switching to them.

[Compound primary keys](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html) are also supported. Isn't this:

```sql
CONSTRAINT unique_paper_day UNIQUE (paper_id, day_id)
```

really just your primary key?

`day_id` isn't particularly an ID. It's a `day` integer, similar to your `year` and `month` (so long as I understand your schema). A rename is in order, and this should also receive a check constraint.

You already use the connection as a context manager, which is good; but [that implies a commit](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager). That means that you should not need to commit manually.

I've said as much in your other question, but you shouldn't be dynamically generating queries as you are in `generate_sql_query`, and you need to delete `return []`.

This is problematic:

```
cost_and_delivery_data = [
    get_cost_and_delivery_data(paper_id)
    for paper_id, in papers # type: ignore
]
```

because `get_cost_and_delivery_data` will open and close the connection on every iteration. Instead, pass a connection in.

`undelivered_dates.dates` is a classic normalisation error. Newcomers to RDBMS often say "I want to store an array", and if they're determined enough (as you are), they might even succeed. But this is not a good idea. There should be a separate row in this table for each date.

*get the names of all papers that already exist* is a lie. That query doesn't fetch all names of papers that exist; it fetches the name of all existing papers whose name matches the given name. But more importantly, you don't actually care about the name; you only care about the existence of the row, so write

```sql
select exists(
    select 1 from papers where name=?
)
```

Further to that, your `select exists` and `insert` should not be separated, but should be in the same query. After executing it, check `rowcount` to see if anything was successfully inserted.

Even more combination: do not have a separate select for *get the ID of the paper that was just added*; that should also be in the same statement using a [returning clause](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_returning.html).

`paper_days_cost` and `paper_days_delivered` appear to have the same keys. If they have the same existence characteristics, they should be merged into one table.

I encourage you to work on the above, and (after some time has passed and you've gathered enough feedback from the community) post a new question with your updated code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! `day_id` (values 0-6) is an ID, for the day of the week. In my Core code, I've never defined "0 ==> Monday" or something like that, instead relying on `day_name` from the `calendar` module. The hope is that this won't tie the app down to my conventions, and adapt for the user (let Sunday be the first day of the week, for instance). `day_id` indexes `list(day_name)`, functioning as an ID for that list. Agree with everything else. Not sure how I missed out normalizing, but I'll try to achieve 3NF before posting a revised version.