# UPDATE on Newspaper Bill Calculator CLI with Python (3 of 3, Database)

Tags: python, unit-testing, database, sqlite, crud

Code is posted after explanation.

Due to the size of the project, this is being posted in three separate posts. This also ensures each post is more focused.

- Post 1 of 3, Core: [UPDATE 1 on Newspaper Bill Calculator CLI with Python (1 of 3, Core)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/276927/257004)
- Post 2 of 3, CLI: [UPDATE 1 on Newspaper Bill Calculator CLI with Python (2 of 3, CLI)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/276928/257004)

This is a follow-up to an [earlier version of the same project](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/276225/newspaper-bill-calculator-cli-with-python-1-of-3-core). The feedback from the last round is tracked in an [issue](https://github.com/eccentricOrange/npbc/issues/20).

---

### What is this?

This application helps you calculate monthly newspaper bills. The goal is to generate a message that I can paste into WhatsApp and send to my newspaper vendor. The end result here is a CLI tool that will be later used as a back-end to build GUIs (hence learn about: C#, HTML/CSS/JS, Flutter). In its current form, everything will be "compiled" by PyInstaller into one-file stand-alone executables for the end-user using GitHub Actions.

The other important goal was to be a testbed for learning a bunch of new tools: more Python libraries, SQL connectors, GitHub Actions (CI/CD, if I understand correctly), unit tests, CLI libraries, type-hinting, regex. I had [earlier built](https://github.com/eccentricOrange/Newspaper-Bill-Calculator-v2) this on a different platform, so I now have a solid idea of how this application is used.

### Key concepts

1. Each newspaper has a certain cost per day of the week
2. Each newspaper may or may not be delivered on a given day
3. Each newspaper has a name, and a number called a key
4. You may register any dates when you didn't receive a paper in advance using the `addudl` command
5. Once you calculate, the results are displayed and logged.

### What files exist?

(ignoring conventional ones like `README` and `requirements.txt`)

| File | Purpose/Description | Review |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `npbc_core.py` | Provide the core functionality: the calculation, parsing and validation of user input, interaction with the DB etc. Later on, some functionality from this will be extracted to create server-side code that can service more users, but I have to learn a lot more before getting there. | Please review this. |
| `npbc_regex.py` | Contains all the regex statements used to validate and parse user input. | Please review this. |
| `npbc_exceptions.py` | Defines classes for all the custom exceptions used by the core and the CLI. | Please review this. |
| `npbc_cli.py` | Import functionality from `npbc_core.py` and wrap a CLI layer on it using `argparse`. Also provide some additional validation. | Please review this. |
| `npbc_updater.py` | Provide a utility to update the application on the user's end. | Don't bother reviewing this (code not included). |
| `test_core.py` | Test the functionality of the core file (pytest), except anything to do with the database. | Please review this. |
| `test_db.py` | Test the functionality of the core file (pytest), for anything to do with the database. | Please review this. |
| `test_regex.py` | Test the functionality of the regex statements. | Please review this. |
| `data/schema.sql` | Database schema. In my local environment, the `data` folder also has a test database file (but I don't want to upload this online). | Please review this if you can (not high priority). |
| `data/test.sql` | SQL statements to generate test data for `test_db.py`. | Please review this if you can (not high priority). |

---

## `data/schema.sql`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS papers (
    paper_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT unique_paper_name UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cost_and_delivery_data (
    paper_day_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    paper_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES papers(paper_id),
    day_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cost REAL NOT NULL,
    delivered INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT unique_paper_day UNIQUE (paper_id, day_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS undelivered_strings (
    string_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    year INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (year >= 0),
    month INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (month >= 0 AND month <= 12),
    paper_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES papers(paper_id),
    string TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logs (
    log_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    paper_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES papers(paper_id),
    timestamp TEXT NOT NULL,
    month INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (month >= 0 AND month <= 12),
    year INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (year >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT unique_log UNIQUE (timestamp, paper_id, month, year)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS undelivered_dates_logs (
    undelivered_dates_log_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    log_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES logs(log_id),
    date_not_delivered TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cost_logs (
    cost_log_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    log_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES logs(log_id),
    cost REAL NOT NULL
);
```

## `data/test.sql`

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS papers (
    paper_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT unique_paper_name UNIQUE (name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cost_and_delivery_data (
    paper_day_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    paper_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES papers(paper_id),
    day_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    cost REAL NOT NULL,
    delivered INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT unique_paper_day UNIQUE (paper_id, day_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS undelivered_strings (
    string_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    year INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (year >= 0),
    month INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (month >= 0 AND month <= 12),
    paper_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES papers(paper_id),
    string TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logs (
    log_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    paper_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES papers(paper_id),
    timestamp TEXT NOT NULL,
    month INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (month >= 0 AND month <= 12),
    year INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (year >= 0),
    CONSTRAINT unique_log UNIQUE (timestamp, paper_id, month, year)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS undelivered_dates_logs (
    undelivered_dates_log_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    log_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES logs(log_id),
    date_not_delivered TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cost_logs (
    cost_log_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    log_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES logs(log_id),
    cost REAL NOT NULL
);
```

## `test_db.py`

```py
"""
test data-dependent functions from the core
- all of these depend on the DB
- for consistency, the DB will always be initialised with the same data
- the test data is contained in `data/test.sql`
- the schema is the same as the core (`data/schema.sql` during development)
"""


from datetime import date, datetime
from pathlib import Path
from sqlite3 import connect
from typing import Counter

from pytest import raises

import npbc_cli
import npbc_core
import npbc_exceptions

ACTIVE_DIRECTORY = Path("data")
DATABASE_PATH = ACTIVE_DIRECTORY / "npbc.db"
SCHEMA_PATH = ACTIVE_DIRECTORY / "schema.sql"
TEST_SQL = ACTIVE_DIRECTORY / "test.sql"


def setup_db():
    DATABASE_PATH.unlink(missing_ok=True)

    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        connection.executescript(SCHEMA_PATH.read_text())
        connection.commit()
        connection.executescript(TEST_SQL.read_text())

    connection.close()


def test_db_creation():
    DATABASE_PATH.unlink(missing_ok=True)
    assert not DATABASE_PATH.exists()

    try:
        npbc_cli.main([])

    except SystemExit:
        pass

    assert DATABASE_PATH.exists()


def test_get_papers():
    setup_db()

    known_data = [
        (1, 'paper1', 0, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 1, 1, 6.4),
        (1, 'paper1', 2, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 3, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 4, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 5, 1, 7.9),
        (1, 'paper1', 6, 1, 4),
        (2, 'paper2', 0, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 1, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 2, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 3, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 4, 1, 3.4),
        (2, 'paper2', 5, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 6, 1, 8.4),
        (3, 'paper3', 0, 1, 2.4),
        (3, 'paper3', 1, 1, 4.6),
        (3, 'paper3', 2, 0, 0),
        (3, 'paper3', 3, 0, 0),
        (3, 'paper3', 4, 1, 3.4),
        (3, 'paper3', 5, 1, 4.6),
        (3, 'paper3', 6, 1, 6)
    ]

    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_papers()) == Counter(known_data)


def test_get_undelivered_strings():
    setup_db()

    known_data = [
        (1, 1, 2020, 11, '5'),
        (2, 1, 2020, 11, '6-12'),
        (3, 2, 2020, 11, 'sundays'),
        (4, 3, 2020, 11, '2-tuesday'),
        (5, 3, 2020, 10, 'all')
    ]

    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_undelivered_strings()) == Counter(known_data)
    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_undelivered_strings(string_id=3)) == Counter([known_data[2]])
    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_undelivered_strings(month=11)) == Counter(known_data[:4])
    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_undelivered_strings(paper_id=1)) == Counter(known_data[:2])
    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_undelivered_strings(paper_id=1, string='6-12')) == Counter([known_data[1]])

    with raises(npbc_exceptions.StringNotExists):
        npbc_core.get_undelivered_strings(year=1986)


def test_delete_paper():
    setup_db()

    npbc_core.delete_existing_paper(2)

    known_data = [
        (1, 'paper1', 0, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 1, 1, 6.4),
        (1, 'paper1', 2, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 3, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 4, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 5, 1, 7.9),
        (1, 'paper1', 6, 1, 4),
        (3, 'paper3', 0, 1, 2.4),
        (3, 'paper3', 1, 1, 4.6),
        (3, 'paper3', 2, 0, 0),
        (3, 'paper3', 3, 0, 0),
        (3, 'paper3', 4, 1, 3.4),
        (3, 'paper3', 5, 1, 4.6),
        (3, 'paper3', 6, 1, 6)
    ]

    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_papers()) == Counter(known_data)

    with raises(npbc_exceptions.PaperNotExists):
        npbc_core.delete_existing_paper(7)
        npbc_core.delete_existing_paper(2)


def test_add_paper():
    setup_db()

    known_data = [
        (1, 'paper1', 0, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 1, 1, 6.4),
        (1, 'paper1', 2, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 3, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 4, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 5, 1, 7.9),
        (1, 'paper1', 6, 1, 4),
        (2, 'paper2', 0, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 1, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 2, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 3, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 4, 1, 3.4),
        (2, 'paper2', 5, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 6, 1, 8.4),
        (3, 'paper3', 0, 1, 2.4),
        (3, 'paper3', 1, 1, 4.6),
        (3, 'paper3', 2, 0, 0),
        (3, 'paper3', 3, 0, 0),
        (3, 'paper3', 4, 1, 3.4),
        (3, 'paper3', 5, 1, 4.6),
        (3, 'paper3', 6, 1, 6),
        (4, 'paper4', 0, 1, 4),
        (4, 'paper4', 1, 0, 0),
        (4, 'paper4', 2, 1, 2.6),
        (4, 'paper4', 3, 0, 0),
        (4, 'paper4', 4, 0, 0),
        (4, 'paper4', 5, 1, 1),
        (4, 'paper4', 6, 1, 7)
    ]

    npbc_core.add_new_paper(
        'paper4',
        [True, False, True, False, False, True, True],
        [4, 0, 2.6, 0, 0, 1, 7]
    )

    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_papers()) == Counter(known_data)

    with raises(npbc_exceptions.PaperAlreadyExists):
        npbc_core.add_new_paper(
            'paper4',
            [True, False, True, False, False, True, True],
            [4, 0, 2.6, 0, 0, 1, 7]
        )


def test_edit_paper():
    setup_db()

    known_data = [
        (1, 'paper1', 0, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 1, 1, 6.4),
        (1, 'paper1', 2, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 3, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 4, 0, 0),
        (1, 'paper1', 5, 1, 7.9),
        (1, 'paper1', 6, 1, 4),
        (2, 'paper2', 0, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 1, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 2, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 3, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 4, 1, 3.4),
        (2, 'paper2', 5, 0, 0),
        (2, 'paper2', 6, 1, 8.4),
        (3, 'paper3', 0, 1, 2.4),
        (3, 'paper3', 1, 1, 4.6),
        (3, 'paper3', 2, 0, 0),
        (3, 'paper3', 3, 0, 0),
        (3, 'paper3', 4, 1, 3.4),
        (3, 'paper3', 5, 1, 4.6),
        (3, 'paper3', 6, 1, 6)
    ]

    npbc_core.edit_existing_paper(
        1,
        days_delivered=[True, False, True, False, False, True, True],
        days_cost=[6.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7.9, 4]
    )

    known_data[0] = (1, 'paper1', 0, 1, 6.4)
    known_data[1] = (1, 'paper1', 1, 0, 0)
    known_data[2] = (1, 'paper1', 2, 1, 0)
    known_data[3] = (1, 'paper1', 3, 0, 0)
    known_data[4] = (1, 'paper1', 4, 0, 0)
    known_data[5] = (1, 'paper1', 5, 1, 7.9)
    known_data[6] = (1, 'paper1', 6, 1, 4)

    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_papers()) == Counter(known_data)

    npbc_core.edit_existing_paper(
        3,
        name="New paper"
    )

    known_data[14] = (3, 'New paper', 0, 1, 2.4)
    known_data[15] = (3, 'New paper', 1, 1, 4.6)
    known_data[16] = (3, 'New paper', 2, 0, 0)
    known_data[17] = (3, 'New paper', 3, 0, 0)
    known_data[18] = (3, 'New paper', 4, 1, 3.4)
    known_data[19] = (3, 'New paper', 5, 1, 4.6)
    known_data[20] = (3, 'New paper', 6, 1, 6)

    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_papers()) == Counter(known_data)

    with raises(npbc_exceptions.PaperNotExists):
        npbc_core.edit_existing_paper(7, name="New paper")


def test_delete_string():
    known_data = [
        (1, 1, 2020, 11, '5'),
        (2, 1, 2020, 11, '6-12'),
        (3, 2, 2020, 11, 'sundays'),
        (4, 3, 2020, 11, '2-tuesday'),
        (5, 3, 2020, 10, 'all')
    ]

    setup_db()
    npbc_core.delete_undelivered_string(string='all')
    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_undelivered_strings()) == Counter(known_data[:4])

    setup_db()
    npbc_core.delete_undelivered_string(month=11)
    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_undelivered_strings()) == Counter([known_data[4]])

    setup_db()
    npbc_core.delete_undelivered_string(paper_id=1)
    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_undelivered_strings()) == Counter(known_data[2:])

    setup_db()

    with raises(npbc_exceptions.StringNotExists):
        npbc_core.delete_undelivered_string(string='not exists')

    with raises(npbc_exceptions.NoParameters):
        npbc_core.delete_undelivered_string()


def test_add_string():
    setup_db()

    known_data = [
        (1, 1, 2020, 11, '5'),
        (2, 1, 2020, 11, '6-12'),
        (3, 2, 2020, 11, 'sundays'),
        (4, 3, 2020, 11, '2-tuesday'),
        (5, 3, 2020, 10, 'all')
    ]

    npbc_core.add_undelivered_string(4, 2017, 3, 'sundays')
    known_data.append((6, 3, 2017, 4, 'sundays'))
    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_undelivered_strings()) == Counter(known_data)

    npbc_core.add_undelivered_string(9, 2017, None, '11')
    known_data.append((7, 1, 2017, 9, '11'))
    known_data.append((8, 2, 2017, 9, '11'))
    known_data.append((9, 3, 2017, 9, '11'))
    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_undelivered_strings()) == Counter(known_data)


def test_save_results():
    setup_db()

    known_data = [
        (1, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', '2020-01-01'),
        (1, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', '2020-01-02'),
        (2, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', '2020-01-01'),
        (2, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', '2020-01-05'),
        (2, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', '2020-01-03'),
        (1, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', 105.0),
        (2, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', 51.0),
        (3, 1, 2020, '04/01/2022 01:05:42 AM', 647.0)
    ]

    npbc_core.save_results(
        {1: 105, 2: 51, 3: 647},
        {
            1: set([date(month=1, day=1, year=2020), date(month=1, day=2, year=2020)]),
            2: set([date(month=1, day=1, year=2020), date(month=1, day=5, year=2020), date(month=1, day=3, year=2020)]),
            3: set()
        },
        1,
        2020,
        datetime(year=2022, month=1, day=4, hour=1, minute=5, second=42)
    )

    assert Counter(npbc_core.get_logged_data()) == Counter(known_data)
```

## All code that uses the DB in `npbc_core.py`

#### Setup

```py
## paths for the folder containing schema and database files
# during normal use, the DB will be in ~/.npbc (where ~ is the user's home directory) and the schema will be bundled with the executable
# during development, the DB and schema will both be in "data"

# default to PRODUCTION
DATABASE_DIR = Path.home() / '.npbc'
SCHEMA_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / 'schema.sql'

# if in a development environment, set the paths to the data folder
if environ.get('NPBC_DEVELOPMENT') or environ.get('CI'):
    DATABASE_DIR = Path('data')
    SCHEMA_PATH = Path('data') / 'schema.sql'

DATABASE_PATH = DATABASE_DIR / 'npbc.db'

## list constant for names of weekdays
WEEKDAY_NAMES = list(weekday_names_iterable)

def setup_and_connect_DB() -> None:
    """ensure DB exists and it's set up with the schema"""

    DATABASE_DIR.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    DATABASE_PATH.touch(exist_ok=True)

    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        connection.executescript(SCHEMA_PATH.read_text())

    connection.close()
```

#### Fetch cost and delivery data for calculation

```py
def get_cost_and_delivery_data(paper_id: int, connection: Connection) -> list[tuple[bool, float]]:
    """get the cost and delivery data for a given paper from the DB"""
    
    query = """
        SELECT delivered, cost FROM cost_and_delivery_data
        WHERE paper_id = ?
        ORDER BY day_id;
    """

    # return a list but convert the delivery data to Booleans because SQLite won't do it
    return list(map(
        lambda row: (bool(row[0]), row[1]),
        connection.execute(query, (paper_id,)).fetchall()
    ))
```

#### Calculate the cost

```py
def calculate_cost_of_all_papers(undelivered_strings: dict[int, list[str]], month: int, year: int) -> tuple[
    dict[int, float],
    float,
    dict[int, set[date_type]]
]:
    """calculate the cost of all papers for the full month
    - return data about the cost of each paper, the total cost, and dates when each paper was not delivered"""

    NUMBER_OF_EACH_WEEKDAY = list(get_number_of_each_weekday(month, year))
    cost_and_delivery_data = {}

    # get the IDs of papers that exist
    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        papers = connection.execute("SELECT paper_id FROM papers;").fetchall()

        # get the data about cost and delivery for each paper
        cost_and_delivery_data = [
            get_cost_and_delivery_data(paper_id, connection)
            for paper_id, in papers # type: ignore
        ]

    connection.close()

    # initialize a "blank" dictionary that will eventually contain any dates when a paper was not delivered
    undelivered_dates: dict[int, set[date_type]] = {
        int(paper_id): set()
        for paper_id, in papers # type: ignore
    }

    # calculate the undelivered dates for each paper
    for paper_id, strings in undelivered_strings.items():
        undelivered_dates[paper_id].update(
            parse_undelivered_strings(month, year, *strings)
        )

    # calculate the cost of each paper
    costs = {
        paper_id: calculate_cost_of_one_paper(
            NUMBER_OF_EACH_WEEKDAY,
            undelivered_dates[paper_id],
            cost_and_delivery_data[index]
        )
        for index, (paper_id,) in enumerate(papers) # type: ignore
    }

    # calculate the total cost of all papers
    total = sum(costs.values())

    return costs, total, undelivered_dates
```

#### Format user output and save data to logs

```py
def save_results(
    costs: dict[int, float],
    undelivered_dates: dict[int, set[date_type]],
    month: int,
    year: int,
    custom_timestamp: datetime | None = None
) -> None:
    """save the results of undelivered dates to the DB
    - save the dates any paper was not delivered
    - save the final cost of each paper"""

    timestamp = (custom_timestamp if custom_timestamp else datetime.now()).strftime(r'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:

        # create log entries for each paper
        log_ids = {
            paper_id: connection.execute(
                """
                INSERT INTO logs (paper_id, month, year, timestamp)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
                RETURNING logs.log_id;
                """,
                (paper_id, month, year, timestamp)
            ).fetchone()[0]
            for paper_id in costs.keys()
        }

        # create cost entries for each paper
        for paper_id, log_id in log_ids.items():
            connection.execute(
                """
                INSERT INTO cost_logs (log_id, cost)
                VALUES (?, ?);
                """,
                (log_id, costs[paper_id])
            )

        # create undelivered date entries for each paper
        for paper_id, dates in undelivered_dates.items():
            for date in dates:
                connection.execute(
                    """
                    INSERT INTO undelivered_dates_logs (log_id, date_not_delivered)
                    VALUES (?, ?);
                    """,
                    (log_ids[paper_id], date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
                )

    connection.close()


def format_output(costs: dict[int, float], total: float, month: int, year: int) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    """format the output of calculating the cost of all papers"""
    
    # output the name of the month for which the total cost was calculated
    yield f"For {date_type(year=year, month=month, day=1).strftime(r'%B %Y')},\n"

    # output the total cost of all papers
    yield f"*TOTAL*: {total:.2f}"

    # output the cost of each paper with its name
    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        papers = dict(connection.execute("SELECT paper_id, name FROM papers;").fetchall())

        for paper_id, cost in costs.items():
            yield f"{papers[paper_id]}: {cost:.2f}"

    connection.close()
```

#### Add, edit, or delete a paper

```py
def add_new_paper(name: str, days_delivered: list[bool], days_cost: list[float]) -> None:
    """add a new paper
    - do not allow if the paper already exists"""

    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        
        # check if the paper already exists
        if connection.execute(
            "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM papers WHERE name = ?);",
            (name,)).fetchone()[0]:
            raise npbc_exceptions.PaperAlreadyExists(f"Paper \"{name}\" already exists."
        )

        # insert the paper
        paper_id = connection.execute(
            "INSERT INTO papers (name) VALUES (?) RETURNING papers.paper_id;",
            (name,)
        ).fetchone()[0]

        # create cost and delivered entries for each day
        for day_id, (delivered, cost) in enumerate(zip(days_delivered, days_cost)):
            connection.execute(
                "INSERT INTO cost_and_delivery_data (paper_id, day_id, delivered, cost) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);",
                (paper_id, day_id, delivered, cost)
            )

    connection.close()


def edit_existing_paper(
    paper_id: int,
    name: str | None = None,
    days_delivered: list[bool] | None = None,
    days_cost: list[float] | None = None
) -> None:
    """edit an existing paper
    do not allow if the paper does not exist"""

    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        
        # check if the paper exists
        if not connection.execute(
            "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM papers WHERE paper_id = ?);",
            (paper_id,)).fetchone()[0]:
            raise npbc_exceptions.PaperNotExists(f"Paper with ID {paper_id} does not exist."
        )

        # update the paper name
        if name is not None:
            connection.execute(
                "UPDATE papers SET name = ? WHERE paper_id = ?;",
                (name, paper_id)
            )

        # update the costs of each day
        if days_cost is not None:
            for day_id, cost in enumerate(days_cost):
                connection.execute(
                    "UPDATE cost_and_delivery_data SET cost = ? WHERE paper_id = ? AND day_id = ?;",
                    (cost, paper_id, day_id)
                )

        # update the delivered status of each day
        if days_delivered is not None:
            for day_id, delivered in enumerate(days_delivered):
                connection.execute(
                    "UPDATE cost_and_delivery_data SET delivered = ? WHERE paper_id = ? AND day_id = ?;",
                    (delivered, paper_id, day_id)
                )

    connection.close()


def delete_existing_paper(paper_id: int) -> None:
    """delete an existing paper
    - do not allow if the paper does not exist"""

    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        
        # check if the paper exists
        if not connection.execute(
            "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM papers WHERE paper_id = ?);",
            (paper_id,)).fetchone()[0]:
            raise npbc_exceptions.PaperNotExists(f"Paper with ID {paper_id} does not exist."
        )

        # delete the paper
        connection.execute(
            "DELETE FROM papers WHERE paper_id = ?;",
            (paper_id,)
        )

        # delete the costs and delivery data for the paper
        connection.execute(
            "DELETE FROM cost_and_delivery_data WHERE paper_id = ?;",
            (paper_id,)
        )

    connection.close()
```

#### Add or delete undelivered strings

```py
def add_undelivered_string(month: int, year: int, paper_id: int | None = None, *undelivered_strings: str) -> None:
    """record strings for date(s) paper(s) were not delivered
    - if no paper ID is specified, all papers are assumed"""

    # validate the strings
    validate_undelivered_string(*undelivered_strings)

    # if a paper ID is given
    if paper_id:

        # check that specified paper exists in the database
        with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
            if not connection.execute(
                "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM papers WHERE paper_id = ?);",
                (paper_id,)).fetchone()[0]:
                raise npbc_exceptions.PaperNotExists(f"Paper with ID {paper_id} does not exist."
            )
        
            # add the string(s)
            params = [
                (month, year, paper_id, string)
                for string in undelivered_strings
            ]

            connection.executemany("INSERT INTO undelivered_strings (month, year, paper_id, string) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", params)

        connection.close()

    # if no paper ID is given
    else:

        # get the IDs of all papers
        with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
            paper_ids = [
                row[0]
                for row in connection.execute(
                    "SELECT paper_id FROM papers;"
                )
            ]

            # add the string(s)
            params = [
                (month, year, paper_id, string)
                for paper_id in paper_ids
                for string in undelivered_strings
            ]

            connection.executemany("INSERT INTO undelivered_strings (month, year, paper_id, string) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", params)

        connection.close()


def delete_undelivered_string(
    string_id: int | None = None,
    string: str | None = None,
    paper_id: int | None = None,
    month: int | None = None,
    year: int | None = None
) -> None:
    """delete an existing undelivered string
    - do not allow if the string does not exist"""

    # initialize parameters for the WHERE clause of the SQL query
    parameters = []
    values = []

    # check each parameter and add it to the WHERE clause if it is given
    if string_id:
        parameters.append("string_id")
        values.append(string_id)

    if string:
        parameters.append("string")
        values.append(string)

    if paper_id:
        parameters.append("paper_id")
        values.append(paper_id)

    if month:
        parameters.append("month")
        values.append(month)

    if year:
        parameters.append("year")
        values.append(year)

    # if no parameters are given, raise an error
    if not parameters:
        raise npbc_exceptions.NoParameters("No parameters given.")

    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:

        # check if the string exists
        check_query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM undelivered_strings"

        conditions = ' AND '.join(
            f"{parameter} = ?"
            for parameter in parameters
        )

        if (1,) not in connection.execute(f"{check_query} WHERE {conditions});", values).fetchall():
            raise npbc_exceptions.StringNotExists("String with given parameters does not exist.")

        # if the string did exist, delete it
        delete_query = "DELETE FROM undelivered_strings"

        connection.execute(f"{delete_query} WHERE {conditions};", values)

    connection.close()
```

#### Get papers, undelivered strings, or logged data

```py
def get_papers() -> list[tuple[int, str, int, int, float]]:
    """get all papers
    - returns a list of tuples containing the following fields:
      paper_id, paper_name, day_id, paper_delivered, paper_cost"""

    raw_data = []

    query = """
        SELECT papers.paper_id, papers.name, cost_and_delivery_data.day_id, cost_and_delivery_data.delivered, cost_and_delivery_data.cost
        FROM papers
        INNER JOIN cost_and_delivery_data ON papers.paper_id = cost_and_delivery_data.paper_id
        ORDER BY papers.paper_id, cost_and_delivery_data.day_id;
    """

    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        raw_data = connection.execute(query).fetchall()

    connection.close()

    return raw_data


def get_undelivered_strings(
    string_id: int | None = None,
    month: int | None = None,
    year: int | None = None,
    paper_id: int | None = None,
    string: str | None = None
) -> list[tuple[int, int, int, int, str]]:
    """get undelivered strings
    - the user may specify as many as they want parameters
    - available parameters: string_id, month, year, paper_id, string
    - returns a list of tuples containing the following fields:
      string_id, paper_id, year, month, string"""

    # initialize parameters for the WHERE clause of the SQL query
    parameters = []
    values = []
    data = []

    # check each parameter and add it to the WHERE clause if it is given
    if string_id:
        parameters.append("string_id")
        values.append(string_id)

    if month:
        parameters.append("month")
        values.append(month)

    if year:
        parameters.append("year")
        values.append(year)

    if paper_id:
        parameters.append("paper_id")
        values.append(paper_id)

    if string:
        parameters.append("string")
        values.append(string)


    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:

        # generate the SQL query
        main_query = "SELECT string_id, paper_id, year, month, string FROM undelivered_strings"
        
        if not parameters:
            query = f"{main_query};"

        else:
            conditions = ' AND '.join(
                f"{parameter} = ?"
                for parameter in parameters
            )

            query = f"{main_query} WHERE {conditions};"

        data = connection.execute(query, values).fetchall()
    connection.close()

    # if no data was found, raise an error
    if not data:
        raise npbc_exceptions.StringNotExists("String with given parameters does not exist.")

    return data


def get_logged_data(
    query_paper_id: int | None = None,
    query_log_id: int | None = None,
    query_month: int | None = None,
    query_year: int | None = None,
    query_timestamp: date_type | None = None
) -> Generator[tuple[int, int, int, int, str, str | float], None, None]:
    """get logged data
    - the user may specify as parameters many as they want
    - available parameters: paper_id, log_id, month, year, timestamp
    - yields: tuples containing the following fields:
      log_id, paper_id, month, year, timestamp, date | cost."""

    # initialize parameters for the WHERE clause of the SQL query
    parameters = []
    values = ()

    # check each parameter and add it to the WHERE clause if it is given
    if query_paper_id:
        parameters.append("paper_id")
        values += (query_paper_id,)

    if query_log_id:
        parameters.append("log_id")
        values += (query_log_id,)

    if query_month:
        parameters.append("month")
        values += (query_month,)

    if query_year:
        parameters.append("year")
        values += (query_year,)

    if query_timestamp:
        parameters.append("timestamp")
        values += (query_timestamp.strftime(r'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'),)

    # generate the SQL query
    logs_base_query = """
        SELECT log_id, paper_id, timestamp, month, year
        FROM logs
        ORDER BY log_id, paper_id   
    """

    if parameters:
        conditions = ' AND '.join(
            f"{parameter} = ?"
            for parameter in parameters
        )

        logs_query = f"{logs_base_query} WHERE {conditions};"

    else:
        logs_query = f"{logs_base_query};"

    dates_query = "SELECT log_id, date_not_delivered FROM undelivered_dates_logs;"
    costs_query = "SELECT log_id, cost FROM cost_logs;"

    with connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:
        logs = {
            log_id: [paper_id, month, year, timestamp]
            for log_id, paper_id, timestamp, month, year in connection.execute(logs_query, values).fetchall()
        }

        dates = connection.execute(dates_query).fetchall()
        costs = connection.execute(costs_query).fetchall()

        for log_id, date in dates:
            yield tuple(logs[log_id] + [date])

        for log_id, cost in costs:
            yield tuple(logs[log_id] + [float(cost)])
        
    connection.close()
```

---

If you need it, here is a link to the GitHub repo for this project. It's at the same commit as the code above, and I won't edit this so that any discussion is consistent.

https://github.com/eccentricOrange/npbc/tree/041a949bbba018531ec590a2193523f1530659aa